# this warning appeared An internal error occurred during: "Building". Unable to communicate with XML-RPC server

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, robotframework

I tried to create a Robot project , but I am getting this error : An internal error occurred during: "Building". Unable to communicate with XML-RPC server I tried some solution , but didn't work , and now when I press OK , I can't access to the libraries and the files inside the projects

[image]

My installation is

```
pip                            21.1.1
python-dateutil                 2.8.2
robotframework                  6.0.2
robotframework-datadriver       1.7.0
robotframework-pythonlibcore    4.1.2
robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary  6.1.0
```

- Python 3.8.10 on win32
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - 2022-12

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.